# Does Gödel's Completeness Theorem still hold even if the set of variables is finite?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples

Let $L$ be a first order language with a finite set of variables. Let $T$ be a consistent set of formulas of $L$. Does it follow that there exists a model for $T$?

Comment: What does "consistent" mean, with only a _finite_ number of variables?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey That contradiction is not deducible from $T$. It makes sense according to the proof system I am using.

Comment: What does "finite set of variables" mean, exactly? Variables are usually assumed not to be part of the language, but part of first-order logic in general - you can say $\exists x \phi(x)$ regardless of the specific language. (Though the possible formulas $\phi$ will depend on the language, of course). So if you restrict the number of available languages, you'll have to define *exactly* how the resulting proof system looks like.

Comment: Can you give a reference to your proof system?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey I am using the proof system of Manin's book "A first course in Mathematical logic". As far as I can see, the proof system used in the book does not require the set of variables to be infinite in order to be meaningful.

Comment: @fgp I don't see a problem in having a first order language that uses an alphabet with a finite set of variables

Comment: @Amr The point isn't whether there's a problem or not, the point is that what you describe isn't first-order predicate logic *at all*. The *language* defines the constants, functions and relation symbols, but the *variables* aren't part of the language. They're part of first-order logic *in general*, i.e. we can use variables when forming sentences in *any* language. You certainly *can* restrict the number of allowed variables, but the result is going to be a rather weird kind of logic. For example, you won't generally be able to combine sentences into new onces, as in $\phi \land \theta$.

Comment: @Amr Note that I'm not saying that what you're trying to do doesn't make sense - it might very well do - but only that you need to *explain* it in much more detail. Simply saying "I'm limiting the number of available variables" just leaves to many quesitons unanswered for there to be a sensible answer to your question.

Comment: I'm browsing Yuri Manin, *A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians* (2010), that is the 2nd ed of the 1977 book; see page 56 : **6.2. Theorem** (Gödel) : he consider an "interpretation of L in some set $M$ having cardinality card (alphabet of L) $+ ℵ_0$. (Here and below we always mean the cardinality of the alphabet without the variables.)" I think that the parenthetical note licences us to assume that card (set of *variable*) is $ℵ_0$.

Comment: Uou can see this [post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137843/axiomatization-of-first-order-logic-finitely-many-variables)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible in a meaningful way.

The point of Godel's completeness theorem is that it ties in the syntactical and semantical notions together nicely. However it is hard to figure out you would even come up with a syntactic notions in this case: Here is an example: Suppose your language has two constant symbols $a_{1},a_{2}$ and $T$ says that $a_{1}\neq{a_{2}}$. Now in a reasonable proof system you would expect that the rules would allow you to conclude that $\exists{x_{1}},{x_{2}}$ $\text{s.t.}x_{1}\neq{x_{2}}$. But if you say that there is only one variable allowed then you can't really say that.

Edit: I think that the real question here is that if the conclusion only refers to $n$ variables, is there a proof of it that only involves $\leq{n}$ variables? If that was the case what you are attempting would make sense. But I think the following can be fleshed out give a counter example.

Suppose you only have two variables to play around with and that the language has a unary predicate $P$. Suppose that $T=\{\exists{!x_{1}}\text{ s.t. }Px_{1}\} \cup$  $\{\forall{x_{1}}Px_{1}\}$. Now any model $M$ of $T$ should model that the universe has exactly one element. But a proof I do not think is possible without reference to a third variable (this I'm not sure how to prove, and probably requires a proof analysis which I'm not sure how to do).

Note: I don't have Manin's book. However he would have placed restrictions on where substitutions can be made and the attempt to prove the result by assuming the existence of two elements will fail because of these rules (See my answer here: [A problem with the interpretation of Kleene (Mathematical Logic) restrictions on deduction on FOL](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579115/a-problem-with-the-interpretation-of-kleene-mathematical-logic-restrictions-on/579209#579209)). However in order to show no proof is possible would require a sort of proof analysis in the spirit of Godel's incompleteness which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: "Now in a reasonable proof system you would expect that the rules would allow you to conclude that $\exists{x_{1}},{x_{2}}$ $\text{s.t.}x_{1}\neq{x_{2}}$. But if you say that there is only one variable allowed then you can't really say that." I know, but I really don't see a problem

Comment: @Amr - the issue **is** interesting. The real problem is that **if** we leave the usual assumptions of an *unlimited supply* of individual variables, we are changing the syntax (as per above comments). With only a finite number of them in e.g.formal number theory (with $=, 0, S, +$ and $\times$) we will have only a finite amount of well-formed formulae. So what ? Has someone of us ever seen a formula with, say, one hundred of vars ? What will happen with usual syntactical (derivation, theorem) and semantical (satisfiability, consistency, validity) notions ? I've never thinked to it ...

Comment: @Amr - I know of (but I've not read it) : Alfred Tarski and Steven Givant, [A formalization of set theory without variables](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183555029) (1987) : **without** variables ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Sure we have. The sentence that says there are more than a hundred elements is a formula with more than one hundred variables.

Comment: I agree with you: it is clear that "restricting" the language we loose "expressive capabilities". But we know that f-o language is "unable" to discriminate between strucutre of *infinite* cardinality; if we have only a *finite* amount of vars, we loose also the capability of discriminating between structure of *finite* cardinality. But what about other properties ? This is what is **not** clear to me. Consider e.g.f-o Peano arithmetic : the infinity of its models depends on the number of variables used in the axioms ?

Comment: See my edit to the answer. I'm pretty sure that it works.

Comment: @Mauro: the reason we do not see formulas with one hundred variables is that we hide bound variables within definitions, then we use those definitions in formulating more definitions, etc. etc. I would venture to guess that if you took the statement of some ordinary theorem of calculus, let's say the uniform continuity of a real valued function defined on a compact metric space, and if you translated that statement into the bare minimum language of set theory without any of our favorite real analysis terminology, that you would get a formula with many more than 100 variables.

Comment: @LeeMosher - yes thanks; you are right !

Comment: @Mauro: To assert the infinitude of models of $\sf PA$ you only need two variables $x,y$ and the constant symbol $0$. Then you can write the two axioms: $\forall x\forall y(S(x)=S(y)\rightarrow x=y)$ and $\forall x(x\neq 0\rightarrow\exists y(x=S(y)))$.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** an answer but a *long* comment.

I agree with Danul's answer that a limited supply of *individual* variables can greatly limit the *expressive* capability of the language.

**But** it is well known that f-o logic is not able to express "everything"; in particular, it is not able to discriminate between models with different infinite cardinalities.

Thus, we may suppose that, with only 100 variables, the supposed "finite" f-o logic cannot discriminate between models with more than 100 objects.

**But** we have f-o math theory, like *group theory*, which needs a very limited numbers of variables : exactly three (see Herbert Enderton, *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2nd - 2001), page 93).

For f-o *number theory* [see S.C.Kleene, *Introduction to Metamathematics* (1952), page 82, or Peter Smith, *An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems* (1st ed - 2007), page 77], two variables suffice.

As explained in Asaf's comment, to assert the infinitude of models of $\mathsf {PA}$ we only need two variables $x,y$ and the constant symbol $0$, because it depends on the two axioms :

> $∀x∀y(S(x)=S(y)→x=y)$ and $∀x(x≠0→∃y(x=S(y)))$.

Thus, my perplexity is that, leaving apart the questions of cardinality, I cannot "see" what are the "impacts" of the above limitations: about consistency, completeness, etc.

What about *induction axiom* for number theory (we have only a finite amount of wf formulae in the "finite" f-o logic) ?

The only modern textbook which I know with a discussion about the "ontology" of variables is :

George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1 : Mathematical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521168465) (2003), page 10-on.

I suggest a reflection on this passage [page 12] :

> If we are Platonists, then we have available in the metatheory all sorts of sets, including infinite sets, in particular the set of all natural numbers. We can use any of these items, speak about them, etc., as we please, when we are describing or building the formal theory *within our metatheory*.
>
> Now, if we are not Platonists, then our “real” mathematical world is much more restricted. In one extreme, we have *no* infinite sets. [footnote : A finitist – and don’t forget that Hilbert-style metatheory was finitary, ostensibly for political reasons – will let you have as many integers as you like in one serving, as long as the serving is *finite*. If you ask for more, you can have more, but never the set of all integers or an infinite subset thereof.]
>
> We can still manage to define our formal language! After all, the “nonending” sequence of object variables $v_0, v_1, v_2,$ . . . can be *finitely generated* in at least two different ways, as we have already seen. Thus we can explain (to a true formalist or finitist) that “non-ending sequence” was an unfortunate slip of the tongue, and that we really meant to give a *procedure* of how to generate on demand a *new* object variable, different from whatever ones we may already have.

A final "silly" comment. I think is that we have at least a "pragmatic" refutation for the "finite" f-o language : why stop at 10, or 100, or a billion of individual variables ? we have **no** reason to choose a "specific" limit... thus, assume an *unlimited* supply of them.

*Added - April, 27*

About the original question :

> Let L be a first order language with a finite set of variables. Let $T$ be a consistent set of formulas of L. Does it follow that there exists a model for $T$?

I think YES.

Consider the language for f-o *number thoery*, and "restrict" it to two *individual* variables : $v_0, v_1$; obviously, in this way, we may form only a finite number of wf formulae.

Consider now the so-called system $Q$ of *Robinson Arithmetic*, without *induction schema* [see Peter Smith, page 55]; its seven axioms needs only two variables.

If we "restrict" $Q$ to the "finite" f-o language with only two variables, we have a sub-theory $Q^-$, wich is *sound* ($\mathbb N$ is a model of it) and *consistent*, if $Q$ is (because if we can prove a contradiction in $Q^-$, this proof is *ipso facto* also a proof in $Q$).

The notion of *valid* formula does not change : a formula with only two variable is *valid* if it is *true* in all models.

The issue of *completeness* for the e.g.two-variables "finite" f-o logic is more difficult.

> Are we able to prove the completeness theorem ? i.e. that all valid formulae with only two variables are provable ?

Comment: "Thus, my perplexity is that, leaving apart the questions of cardinality, I cannot "see" what are the "impacts" of the above limitations: about consistency, completeness, etc." I think there will be an impact on completeness as proofs are harder to do now

Comment: "The real issue (see also this post reagrding finite number theory) - according to me - is that it is simply not "interesting"". The reason this question is interesting for me is the following. Suppose that the question of this post has a positive answer. I thought that if $A$ is a formula that is a first order consequence of the set of formulas $\emptyset$, then one can obtain (with a way that is still not clear to me) an upper bound on the length of the shortest proof of $A$. The upper bound will be a function of the number of variables appearing in $A$ and the length of $A$

Comment: Of course the bound will be obtained/proved using the statement that languages that use alphabets with finite variable symbols are still complete (if the statement is true)

Comment: @LeeMosher Are such bounds known, please read my above two comments, thank you.

Comment: @DanulG Are such bounds known, please read my above two comments, thank you.

Comment: @Amr To my knowledge there is no such upper bound. But then again, proof theory isn't really my thing

Comment: @Mauro: I don't think that what you are saying is correct. While it is possible to give the group axioms using just three formulas I don't think that it is possible to prove interesting things without having access to other variables, which is what we really want to do. Also even though I don't have a proof, I'm pretty sure that my example will show that there is no completeness theorem for this particular case.

Comment: Of course, logics with finitely many variable symbols _are_ studied, and have applications in computer science (to, I believe, Database Theory). L. Libkin's _Elements of Finite Model Theory_ devotes a chapter to studying properties of these logics, and references M. Otto's _Bounded Variable Logics and Counting_ as a good text for these.

Comment: @ArthurFischer - thanks for the references !

Comment: The last part answers my question, doesn't it ? !!

Comment: @Amr - but I've written : "I think ..." :)

Comment: Or no, it doesn't. Let L be the first order language I was talking about (the one that uses an alphabet with finitely many variables). Let L' be the first order language obtained by adding an infinite amount of variables to L. It is easy to see $Formulas_L\subseteq Formulas_{L'}$.  $T$ is a consistent subset of $Formulas_L$ does not imply that $T$ is a consistent subset of $Formulas_{L'}$

Comment: The reason why I say this: It might happen that $T$ is actually inconsistent as a subset of $Formulas_{L'}$. But any formal proof from $T$ to contradiction uses more variables than those which $L$ has. As a result $T$ will appear consistent when viewed as set of formulas in $L$

Answer (score 0):

By a quick reading of Manin's book I think the answer to your question is yes, by completeness theorem.

Indeed Manin's proof doesn't seem to require the set of variables to be infinite.

Nonetheless I also suppose the following claim being true:

> Let $L$ and $L'$ be two languages, such that $L \subseteq L'$ and $L'$ is obtained by $L$ just adding an infinite set of variables. For every $L$-formula $\varphi$ and a $L$-theory $T$ then $T \vdash \varphi$ in the language $L$ if and only if $T \vdash \varphi$ in the language $L'$.

One implication is trivial. The idea to prove the other implication should procede in the following way:

- prove that for any proof that uses formulas with variables in $L' \setminus L$ we can replace such formulas with others obtained by substitution of the *wrong variables* with suitable terms of $L$, thus obtaining a proof of the same formula in the language $L$;
- by definition of provability conclude the claim.

Of course this is not a proof but I hope it can give an idea of why it should work.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the suggestion of proving the harder claim: It might happen that the proof in $L'$ at some point uses a formula that has 10 different variable symbols, now if our language $L$ has only NINE variable symbols, I don't know how I will replace those ten variables with suitable variables, what do you think ?

Comment: @Amr Following your argument: if you have to prove an $L$-formula somewhere in your proof you are gonna eliminate the $10$-th variable by an application of a generalization and a particularization (application of modus ponens to formulas of the form $\forall x A(x) \rightarrow A(t)$ for $t$ a term). My conjecture is that by replacing in your proof every occurence of the variable with the term is used in the particolarization you should still be able to have a valid proof. 
Anyway I could be wrong, that's why I said that *I suppose that should work* :)

Comment: Giorgio, I think that is **not** the proof (Manin's or other) that requires the set of var to be *infinite* (tipically, in Henkin-style proofs, it is needed an *infinite* supply of *new* ind constants). It is the "background" f-o language which has an *infinite* supply of ind vars, and in this respect I think that Manin is "standard" (see my comment above with ref to page 56 of 2nd ed of Manin).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree that probably Manin assume the hypothesis of infinite set of variables. Nonetheless my observation is that the proof of completeness theorem doesn't seems requiring the infinity of the set of variables in order to be proven.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa - My "conjecture" is that Completeness Th still works, because Henkin's proof does not "build up" in an efefctive way a proof of the valid formula. But I think there is a "trick" somewhere, because I think that - if we restrict the language to e.g two only free vars - we cannot expect that for a proof of a valid formula of this "class" two vars suffice ...

Comment: See also this [paper](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~ipratt/papers/wroclaw/Ch2.pdf); but I have not found references to the *completeness* issue.